# How to differentiate web fonts font-face font-weights?

Tags: html, css, comparative-review

What do you guys think:

OPTION #1 (same `font-face` name and change `font-weight`)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  src: url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.ttf');
  font-weight: normal;  // THIS IS NORMAL
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  src: url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.ttf');
  font-weight: bold;   // THIS IS SEMI-BOLD
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  src: url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.ttf');
  font-weight: 900;   // THIS IS BOLD
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Then all my elements would use the font-family: ProximaNova and I would control the weight with the font-weight property, using bold and 900 values.

OPTION #2 (change the font-face name itself to control weight):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  src: url('/fonts/ProximaNova.ttf');
  font-weight: normal;  // ALWAYS NORMAL
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: ProximaNovaSemiBold;   // THIS IS SEMIBOLD
  src: url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.ttf');
  font-weight: normal;  // ALWAYS NORMAL
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: ProximaNovaBold;       // THIS IS BOLD
  src: url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.ttf');
  font-weight: normal;  // ALWAYS NORMAL
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I would control the weight by selecting different font-family names, like ProximaNova, ProximaNovaSemiBold and ProximaNovaBold and the font-weight would always be normal.

What would you go for?

Comment: In **Option 2** is the third file intended to be `'/fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.ttf'` ?

Comment: @Rounin you're right. The third file should be `'/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.ttf'`. I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Generally I would think the best solution with regard to fonts is the one which involves the downloading of the fewest font files. In both **Option 1**  and **Option 2** you're downloading three font files. Ideally (when you're dealing with the same font and alternate font-weights), if you possibly can, you'll want to download just one font-file.

Answer (score 1):

Always option 1. That way it will correctly use bold in cases when the browser doesn't support or can't download the fonts.

EDIT: One more point I've noticed just now: Don't use `bold` (700) for "semi-bold". Most font creators suggest a font-weight value for each variant. Usually it's 600 for "semi-bold" (and 500 for "medium").